# Value Counts with Condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I use a filter for if a column is = for a value counts?

For example

If I have df column below as:

```
Column
Happy
Sad
Mad
Glad
Happy 
Mad
Glad 
Glad
```

I want to run a `df['Column'].value_counts(normalize = True)`

But I only want to see the % for Glad, this is a sample df, but the actual df as many volume values and instead of sifting through I just want to see the % for Glad for example. Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `df.groupby('column').count()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.loc['Glad']` to the end of your code, because [`value_counts()` creates a pandas series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) allowing you to filter for `Glad` using `loc`:

```
df['Column'].value_counts(normalize=True).loc['Glad']
0.375
```

OR you can use `shape[0]` to get total rows of filtered dataframe for `'Glad'` values as a proportion of total rows of the full dataframe:

```
df[df['Column'] == 'Glad'].shape[0] / df.shape[0]
0.375
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples, this will give all column's percentage here.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Column'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

OR taking inspiration from David answer to get string Glad's percentage only use `.loc` for above solution.

```
df['Column'].value_counts(normalize=True).loc['Glad'] * 100
```